# HTML not showing up on React webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router

So as the title suggests, Im looking for a reason as to why my webpage is not showing up on the website

Here is the App.js file

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Post from "./Post.js";

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((response) => {
      setPosts(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">All Posts</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <h1>All Posts</h1>
            <ul>
              {posts.map((post) => (
                <li key={post.id}>
                  <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/posts/:id">
            <Post />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I made Post.js a separate js file from App like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

function Post() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
    const id = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`).then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data);
      });
    }, [id]);
  
    if (!post) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Post;
```

The site is running as well. I can access everything that is there, but for some reason, it is just a blank page.
I hope you can help me with this issue. Thank you

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: yes. There is this `Uncaught Error: [h1] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`

Comment: okay so it has to do with h1. anything that can work? Maybe form?

Comment: What version of React Router are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly put the content to be rendered under `<Route>`. Instead, set the `element` attribute on the `<Route>`.

For example:

```
<Route path="/posts/:id" element={<Post/>}/>
```

You also need to extract the content for all posts into a separate component.

```
<Route path="/" element={<AllPosts/>}>
```

Comment: If you're not using React Router v6, then use the `component` attribute: `<Route path="/posts/:id" component={Post}/>`